# How to load balance mutiport traffic using HAProxy

Tags: tcp, load-balancing, haproxy

I have 2 servers that host an application that listens to mutiple ports.

Is there a way to load traffic between these servers using HAProxy?

I tried this in configuration, but it didn't work:

`frontend Pool1
    bind 172.17.30.254:100-200
    mode tcp
    default_backend nodes`

`backend nodes
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    server web01 172.30.17.1:100-200 check
    server web02 172.30.17.2:100-200 check
    server web03 172.30.17.3:100-200 check`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a supported configuration.   It also seems to defy a bit of logic.  Why so many ports?  (Why reserved and privileged ports?  Maybe 100-200 is an example...)

If the 101 back-end listeners are all providing a different service, then you need 101 front ends and back ends (or "listen" proxies, which can contain both).  If they are not providing a different service each, then you don't need 101 listeners on HAProxy, but you still need the back-ends.